# How to compare time/date in different formats?

Tags: python, datetime

Let's say I am pulling the date of a file using this command:

```
>> date_created = time.ctime(os.path.getctime(latest_file))
>> print (date_created)
Thu Aug 17 13:44:19 2017
```

How can I say compare this date to today or tomorrow for example? How can I pull out specifically Aug 17 and say:

psuedocode:

```
if (Aug 17 = today){ 
    function()   
}
else{
    break
}
```

Essentially, I want to have a check whether or not the file was created today, and if it was then perform the function.

Let's say I am pulling the current date in this form:

```
date_time = time.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
```

Comment: Don't compare the *strings*. Compare the date-objects.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `datetime` to convert the timestamp to a `datetime.datetime` object and check the date against `today`'s date.

Example -

```
from datetime import datetime

date_created = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(latest_file))
if date_created.date() == datetime.now().date():
    #Do your logic
```

---

You can use `timedelta` to get `tomorrow` or `yesterday`'s datetime object. Example -

```
from datetime import timedelta
tomorrow = datetime.datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)
```

Similarly, you can use `-1` for yesterday and so on.